# android device is not visible for run eclipse

Tags: android, android-testing

I try to test my application with real device (samsung galaxi 2) in eclipse, however device is not visible. The settings in the device is not a problem because I can run tests on another comp. In eclipse google usb driver is installed. What else can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your driver is correctly installed (driver for debug), and the USB computer connection is set to the correspondant type (Media device (MTP), Camera (PTP), Mass storage (UMS))

Comment: What do you mean by:  correctly installed (driver for debug)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the minimum SDK in the manifest is lower than the API of the device :

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>`

Comment: Thanks, but same code works with same devise in different computer. I think it eclipse or comp settings.

Comment: Then in that case @GhoRiser is probably correct. Download Samsung Kies and use it to install the correct drivers to your computer. Once the drivers are installed the device should show up, as long as "USB Debugging" is set to true under the development options on the device settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check all this thinks :

1. -The USB driver is installed : [USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver)
2. -The device is in debug mode : [image: USB debugging]
3. -The USB computer connection (try each mode, and reinstall the driver for each mode): [image: USB computer connection]
4. -Your cable is not damaged ^^

Note : there are too driver to install, one without USB debugging enabled, and one with USB debugging enabled